# Evaluate Post fix with negative numbers

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to get my postfix to evaluate negative numbers.

My infix to postfix seems to work fine with the negative number, such as example from my program..
infix: (-3)+5*3
postfix : 3-53*+

Here is my evaluation method, I know the less code to look through the better, if you would like to see any other of my code just let me know. I have tried many things but have had no luck, any suggestions or advise would be appreciated!

```
    public int evaluate(String evalute){
   int number1;
   int number2;
   int result = 0;
   int finalResult = 0;

   Stack<Integer> d = new Stack<Integer>();

   for(int i = 0; i < evalute.length(); i++){
     char curChar = evalute.charAt(i);
     if(curChar >= 48 && curChar <= 57){
       int store = curChar;
       store -=48;
       d.push(store);

     }

     else if(curChar == '+'){
       number1 = d.pop();
       number2 = d.pop();
       result = number1 + number2;
       d.push(result);
     }

     else if(curChar == '-'){
       number1 = d.pop();
       number2 = d.pop();
       result = number2 - number1;
       d.push(result);
   }
     else if(curChar =='*'){
       number1 = d.pop();
       number2 = d.pop();
       System.out.println(result = number1 * number2);
       d.push(result);
     }
     else if(curChar =='/'){
       number1 = d.pop();
       number2 = d.pop();
       result = number2 / number1;
       d.push(result);
     }
   }


   finalResult = d.pop();
   return finalResult;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take your example

infix: (-3)+5*3 postfix : 3-53*+

```
EVAUATION
push 3

read - ---> you have no 2 elements in the stack -> EXCEPTION 
(or by luck you can have 2 but is not the behavior you want)
```

This far seems everything ok, but.. how do you distinguish the unary minus from the binary minus? When you read 3 - 3 do you read a subtraction operation with two operands or two raw operands with inverse sign?

The most easy solution to adopt is to use a different symbol to mark the negative numbers, like `!` the letter `N` or whatever different from minus it self, other wise when you read minus you pop off 2 elements from the stack and you perform the subtraction.

Instead you want to read a sign like `!` you pop off 1 element (`d`) and you push back into the stack `-d`..

so from (-3)+5*3 postfix : 3!53*+

```
EVALUATION
push 3

read ! --> pop 3 and push -3

push 5 - push 3

read * ---> pop 5 - pop 3 push 3*5

read + ---> pop 15 (= 3*5) pop -3 and push 15 + (-)3
```

by the usage of such two different symbols you have solved your problem..

Answer (score -1):

Well i guess it's in the parsing the string phase.
your parser should detect whether it's a negative or positive, after generating the tokens, you can then proceed to converting infix to postfix and evaluate the postfix. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Add some more details, maybe a code block to clarify your answer.